# any good OSGi remote service references/books/tutorials?

Tags: java, architecture, osgi

First of all, I would like to know if OSGi remove service has been successfully implemented?

I am thinking of a good solution to the very messy system I am currently working on. Standalone java components scattered in a cluster of servers asynchrously communicating via JMS. (btw, it is an electronic trading platform).

I searched the web a while ago looking for a good reference but all I found were articles.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Thank you...

Comment: possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361205/recommended-book-for-osgi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends entirely on what you mean by *successfully*, *implemented* and *available*. :-)

Generally speaking the situation is very sad: none of the readily available implementations really work well or offer what people seem to actually need in practice.

First of all it is important to distinguish between the "Remote Services" and "Remote Service Admin" specs. The former is simply a convention for exposing services in the OSGi service registry; the latter is "the real spec" and includes discovery, coordination between transports, selective import/export control etc. This is the **hard** bit, though there is no reason why a good toolkit/mini-framework for this should not be available as open-source package so that people can concentrate on writing discovery or transport bundles with minimal plumbing.

After looking at the work going on in the Apache CXF RI, ECF and Tuscany SCA (all of which we rejected for production use for various reasons) I started to work on a complete reimplementation, based off of the RI & CT as reference. This implementation is coming along nicely (a major new release is due soon) and is part of the commercial [Nimble](http://www.paremus.com/products/products_nimble.html) distribution by Paremus; see [Remote Services](https://docs.paremus.com/display/NIM20/Remote+Services).
Disclaimer: I work for Paremus.

So, to answer your question: yes, there is at least one "successful" spec-compliant RemoteServiceAdmin implementation. Whether it is "available" or not is your call. :)

Comment: I agree. The Paremus implementation of Remote Services is currently the only one that is stable, bug-free and standard-compliant enough for production usage. Of the open source implementations, Eclipse ECF is better than CXF though I believe it is still limited to running on Equinox.

Comment: My understanding is that ECF currently doesn't even run on Virgo. It also seems to bleed through into user code.

Comment: It would be helpful to link a bug report as we haven't had any bugs raised against Virgo wrt ECF.

Comment: A few days ago I wrote an article dealing with the topic of the question https://techblog.smc.it/en/2020-07-31/cosa-sono-osgi-remote-services

Answer (score 3):

If its a distributed electronics trading platform - you are probably/possibly interested in low latency and robust recovery from service failure?

In both cases (IMO) the Nimble Remote Services implementation (thanks to Holger) really does lead the pack.

Comment: Thank Richard. Yes latency is a very big deal and recovery. That is why we heavily rely on messaging. I will take a look at the Nimble.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is the Paremus Service Fabric. If you are trying to solve a real problem and you require scale, throughput, flexibility, adaptability, resilience, etc, Paremus provides a distributed OSGi runtime that will meet or exceed your requirements. In fact, the CEO and Founder is a leader in the OSGi Alliance and focuses on the specifications involving Distributed OSGi (RFC 119) and "OSGi Cloud" capabilities. Indeed, he also recently was selected as the President of the OSGi Alliance.

My point is that Paremus is *the* leader in distributed OSGi. Their engineers have been designing and building the capability for several years. This is your best option.